# Error in file: invalid 'description' argument when using read.xlsx()

Tags: r, shiny, openxlsx

I am using R-shiny and am confused on why I am getting the error: Warning: Error in file: invalid 'description' argument. It seems to stem from the code inside the for loop. I am trying to read multiple Excel files and bind them together. I'm also not sure what the 'datapath' argument does so if someone could clarify that for me that would be great.

```
library(shiny)

library(openxlsx)

library(tidyverse)

library("readxl")

library(dplyr)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tracking Statistical Programming Project Timelines"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("files", "Choose XLSX File(s)",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = ".xlsx"),
      
      # # Horizontal line ----
      # tags$hr(),
      # 
      # # Input: Select separator ----
      # radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
      #              choices = c(Comma = ",",
      #                          Semicolon = ";",
      #                          Tab = "\t"),
      #              selected = ","),
      # 
      # # Input: Select quotes ----
      # radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
      #              choices = c(None = "",
      #                          "Double Quote" = '"',
      #                          "Single Quote" = "'"),
      #              selected = '"'),
      # 
      # # Horizontal line ----
      # tags$hr(),
      # 
      # # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      # radioButtons("disp", "Display",
      #              choices = c(Head = "head",
      #                          All = "all"),
      #              selected = "head")
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")
      
    )
    
  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$contents <- renderTable({

      lst1 <- list()

      for(i in 1:length(input$files[,1])){

        lst1[[i]] <- read.xlsx(input$files[[i, 'datapath']])

      }

      total <- bind_rows(lst1, .id = "column_label")
      
      date <- "([0-1]*[0-9][/][0-3]*[0-9][/][0-2]*[0-9]*[0-9]{2})"
      
      total <- total %>%
        select(`ENTER.DATE`, `PROJECT.TYPE`, `PROJECT.NAME`, `STUDY.INVOLVED`, `KEY.MILESTONES`, TASK, SCOPE, PROGRAMMER, `SNAPSHOT.DATE`, `DUE.DATE`, `%COMPLETION`, `START.DATE`, `END.DATE`, ACCOMPLISHED, `RESOURCE.LOCATION`, NOTES, BIOSTATS, `EXTERNAL.TIMELINE`) %>%
        mutate(`SNAPSHOT.DATE` = str_extract(`SNAPSHOT.DATE`, date),
               `DUE.DATE` = str_extract(`DUE.DATE`, date))
      
      return(total)
      
    })

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `read.xlsx(input$files[i, 'datapath'])`. I think you have too many brackets in your current version.

Comment: It didn't fix it

Comment: Try with `renderTable({ shiny::req(input$files) ....`. Otherwise your app starts reading xl-files even if the user hasn't selected any files yet . `req()` checks for that.